# Dojo: event indicating that widgets are rendered

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget

I have a widget on page and javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    dojo.ready(function() {
        dijit.byId("widgetId");
            // oops, widget is not rendered yet, so this code can't find it.
    })

</script>
```

So what event should I listen to which indicates that widget is rendered?

Comment: First of all, add the missing quote.

Comment: Do you have parseOnLoad: true in your dojoConfig? Or are your widgets programmatically inserted?

Comment: I insert this widgets via php library inspired by Zend Dojo helper. It just prints these widgets as html. And I don't have dojoConfig. At least I'm not aware of it. Where should it be?

Comment: See this page: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/djConfig.html#djconfig

Comment: So parseOnLoad should be false or true?

Comment: it should be true.  What the parseOnLoad attribute does it tell the dojo library to look for dijit widgets that are declared in html via the `data-dojo-type` or `dojoType` attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a framework which appears to hide most of the dojo related configurations, the simplest solution to this would be to call the `dojo.parser.parse()` before  accessing any widgets.  This will ensure that all widgets are created and started.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.ready(function() {
        dojo.parser.parse();
        dijit.byId("widgetId");
    })
</script>
```

Comment: That resulted in following error: Tried to register widget with id==dijit_layout_BorderContainer_0 but that id is already registered. I tried to manually set different ids to border containers but the error repeated.